# CORS Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: nginx, phalcon

I am getting this error `The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://localhost.dev',` when I send ajax request to cross server. This is my ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "https://api.domain.com/api/v1/register/phone",
            headers: {
                'x-api-key': 'abc',
                'partner-id': 'xyz'
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
              'somedata': 'xyz'
            }),
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {console.log(xhr)}
        });
    });
});
```

I am using Phalcon and nginx for api.domain. and I am call ajax from http://localhost.dev. I added `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost.dev';`. This is phalcon code.

```
In router.php
$router->add(
'/api/v1/register/phone',
[
    'module' => 'api',
    'controller' => 'phone',
    'action'    => 'index',
]); 
In controller:
class PhoneController extends ControllerBase{

public function indexAction()
{
        $apiKey = $this->request->getHeader('x-api-key');
            return $this->sendJson([
                'status' => 'Unauthorized',
                'message' => $apiKey
            ], 401);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your API on seperate domain and your project on seperate domain?? If it is then Try adding crossOrigin:true in the ajax, It might solve the error.

Comment: then u must use crossOrigin:true in ajax

Answer (score 0):

After reading this article http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/, I have solve my problem by adding these configuration in nginx.

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost.dev';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *'
```

Of course, I need to change 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost.dev' to be configuration. At least, It's fixed issue on my localhost.dev